# Lightning input disabled depending on aura attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I have an `lightning:input` like this (already tried with `not(v.customAddress)`):

```html
<form class="slds-form--inline slds-m-bottom--small">

  <lightning:select
    aura:id="sendTo"
    label="{! $Label.c.Send_To }"
    name="{! $Label.c.Send_To }"
  >
    <option value="{! null }" selected="{! true }">{! 'Select a mail' }</option>

    <aura:iteration items="{! v.addresses }" var="address" >
      <option value="{! address.id }">
              {! join(' ', join(', ',address.street, address.houseNumber), address.postalCode, address.city) }
      </option>
    </aura:iteration>

  </lightning:select>
  <lightning:buttonIcon
    name="Add selected address"
    iconName="utility:add"
    alternativeText="{! 'Select address' }"
    onclick="{! c.selectAddress }"
  />
</form>

<!-- STREET -->
<form class="slds-form--inline slds-m-bottom--small">
    <lightning:input
        aura:id="street"
        type="text"
        label="{! 'Street address' }"
        name="{! 'street' }"
        onchange="{! c.updateAddress }"
        disabled="{! !v.customAddress }"
        value="{! v.address.street }"
        required="{! true }"
    />
</form>
```

An `aura:attribute`like this:

```html
<aura:attribute 
  name="customAddress"  
  type="Boolean"  
  default="true"  
  required="false" 
  access="private" 
/>
```

And a Javascript function in my controller like this:

```js
({

  selectAddress:      function(component, event, helper) {
    const input         = component.find('sendTo'); // A lightning:select
    const addressId     = input.get('v.value'); // The default lightning:option has a {! null } value

    if (addressId && addressId.trim() !== '') {
      component.set('v.address', /* myProcessedObject */);
      component.set('v.customAddress', false); // lightning:input has to be disabled
    } else {
      component.set('v.address', {});
      component.set('v.customAddress', true); // lightning:input has to be enabled
    }

  }

})
```

The first time my function is called AND `component.set('v.customAddress', false);` is reached, field is not disabled.

Sometimes, when `component.set('v.customAddress', true);` is reached, the field is disabled.

Example:

Initial step:
[image: Step 1: initial state]

I selected the address in the dropdown and clicked +
=> `lightning:input`is field and disabled OK
[image: Step 2: I selected the address in the dropdown and clicked +]

I selected the null value from the dropdown and clicked +
=> `lightning:input`is cleaned but not enable NOK
[image: Step 3: I selected the null value in the dropdown and clicked +]

With a different behaviour of the click function:

```js
  selectAddress:      function(component, event, helper) {
    const input         = component.find('sendTo');
    const addressId     = input.get('v.value');

    if (addressId && addressId.trim() !== '') {
      component.find("street").set("v.disabled", true);
    } else {
      component.find("street").set("v.disabled", false);
    }

  }
```

Answering comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/156171/37707:

[image: Default state]

Step one: (has to be disabled)
[image: Step one]

Step two: (has to be enabled)
[image: Step two]

Answer (score 0):

could you just try this one to disable and enable?

```
Disable: component.find("street").set("v.disabled", true); 
Enable: component.find("street").set("v.disabled", false);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53002/discussion-on-answer-by-remy-chen-lightning-input-disabled-depending-on-aura-att).

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.  (The readonly attribute behaves like the disabled attribute)

```
<lightning:input
    aura:id="street"
    type="text"
    label="Street address"
    name="street"
    onchange="{!c.updateAddress}"
    readonly="{!not(v.customAddress)}"
    value="{!v.address.street}"
    required="true"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work or not, but here is my suggestion:

1. Remove the default="true" for the "customAddress"  Boolean attribute (now the default value is false).
2. According to above condition change 'disabled="{!v.customAddress }"' for lightning:input and do other changes if needed